# Why do NSBlocks have to be copied for storage in containers?

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

```
- (void) addABlock 
{
void (^aBlock)(void) = ^() { [someObject doSomething]; };

[self.myMutableArray addObject: aBlock];  // Oops..

[self.myMutableArray addObject: [aBlock copy]];  // works fine
}
```

In the above simplified example I am seeing undefined behavior if the block copy is not performed. This case is specifically listed in apple's ARC transition guide.

The part that I do not understand is **why** I have to manually call copy. The block is created on the stack so a block_copy needs to be performed- that much is clear. NSArray does not call copy, but it should call retain on objects that get added. So why doesn't [NSBlock retain] simply call through to [NSBlock copy] ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://www.galloway.me.uk/2013/05/a-look-inside-blocks-episode-3-block-copy/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

Despite what [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says:

> Blocks “just work” when you pass blocks up the stack in ARC mode, such as in a return. You don’t have to call Block Copy any more. You still need to use `[^{} copy]` when passing “down” the stack into `arrayWithObjects:` and other methods that do a retain.

it's **no longer necessary** to manually call `copy` on a block when adding it to a container.
The lack of automatic copy in this case has been considered a compiler bug and fixed in `llvm` long time ago.

> "We consider this to be a compiler bug, and it has been fixed for months in the open-source clang repository."

([John McCall](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Feb/msg00071.html), LLVM developer)

I personally tested this in Xcode 5, using the latest Apple LLVM 5.0 compiler.

```
- (NSArray *)blocks {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        [array addObject:^{ return i; }];
    }
    return array;
}

- (void)test {
    for (NSInteger (^block)() in [self blocks]) {
        NSLog(@"%li", block());
    }
}
```

The above example correctly prints

```
0
1
2
```

under ARC and it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in MRC.

Note that this is - finally - coherent with the llvm [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks), which states

> whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a `Block_copy`

meaning that whenever ARC has to retain a pointer and this pointer happens to be a block-pointer type, `Block_copy` will be called instead of `retain`.

---

### Original answer

> The part that I do not understand is why I have to manually call copy.

Blocks are one of the few examples of Objective-C objects allocated on the stack (for performance reasons), so when you return from the method call you lose them, due to the tear down of the current stack frame.

Sending `copy` on a stack-block will call `Block_copy` on it and it will move it on the heap, allowing you to keep a valid reference to the block.

> So why doesn't `[NSBlock retain]` simply call through to `[NSBlock copy]`

This would break the usual semantic of `retain`, which is supposed to return the object itself, with an incremented retain count. Since incrementing a retain count on an stack-block doesn't make any sense, calling `retain` on a stack-block doesn't have any effect.

Apple could have implemented it differently, as you suggest, but they preferred to stick as much as possible to the common contracts of memory management methods.

As a further reference on blocks, you may want to have a look at [this great blog post](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/) by @bbum. It's pre-ARC but the majority of concepts hasn't changed.

Comment: So what happens if I call retain on a block before it has been copied to the heap? Or put differently, why didn't apple implement NSBlock retain like this:
     - (id) retain
    {
        return [self copy];
    }

Comment: If the block is still on the stack, it just doesn't make sense, since it will do nothing. Calling `copy` on a block will call `Block_copy`, which physically moves blocks on the heap. It's also worth noting that extra calls of `Block_copy` (i.e. `copy`) won't produce other copies of the block, but they just will increment the retain count.

Comment: Moreover, that would break the contract of `retain`. `retain` is not supposed to return a copy of an object, but the object itself. Apple could have done so, but they (in my opinion) rightfully decided not to.

Comment: Exactly;  and there is **a ton** of code that'd break if the `retain` contract was broken.  That combined with the promise of ARC (which was in the very early days of implementation) guided the design to not breaking said contract because, under ARC, it could be handled automatically, eventually in all cases.

Comment: @bbum If you have a moment, please take a look at my answer and let me know whether I'm missing something.  Thank you!

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? Is there anything incorrect that I can improve?

Comment: "it's no longer necessary to manually call copy on a block when adding it to a container." This is wrong. "whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a Block_copy" Yes, and it also says "The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call." So in the case when you pass the block literal directly, the specification allows it to be not copied.

Comment: It doesn't. Containers are guaranteed to retain their content, so whenever an object is inserted it is also retained. The specification says that for blocks a semantic retain equates to a Block_Copy, so it's copied. There's a big difference: the block is not copied before being put in the container, but by the container itself, as any other object.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: "The specification says that for blocks a semantic retain equates to a Block_Copy, so it's copied." No it doesn't. The specification says that when the ARC semantics call for a retain on a "value of block-pointer type", it performs a retain instead. There is no expression of block-pointer type inside the NSArray code.

Comment: My interpretation of the sentence is that whenever ARC would invoke `retain` on a pointer, a `Block_Copy` is called in case the pointer if of block type. `NSArray` strongly references its elements, so this will result in a `Block_Copy` inserted by the compiler whenever the elements are of block type.

Comment: Also this was openly recognized as a bug in the compiler and while tests cannot prove anything, they at least strongly support that this is the official behavior. Incidentally, downvoting this answer seems inappropriate to me.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: Please put "@" and the person you are responding to in your responses. ARC is compile time. Whether ARC puts a `retain` or `copy` message into the code is decided at compile-time. `NSArray` always sends a `retain` message to its elements. ARC is compile time, and does not change how the `retain` message works at runtime. Downvoting this answer is appropriate because the answer is *categorically wrong*. It says "it's no longer necessary to manually call copy on a block when adding it to a container"; while it is necessary if you want to follow the ARC specification.

Answer (score 1):

**Under ARC**, you no longer need to manually copy blocks in this case, or in most others.  According to [clang's ARC documentation on blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks)

> With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a __strong parameter variable or reading a __weak variable, whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a Block_copy. The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call.

In other words, most of the time, **retaining a block has the effect of a Block_copy** as you were suggesting should be the case.  In particular, when the block is added to a collection, it is copied!  (More accurately, it is already on the heap.)  Here is some sample code that demonstrates that this is the case.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int counter = 0;
        int total = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            void (^block)(void) = ^{
                NSLog(@"in this block, counter is %d", counter);
            };
            [arr addObject:block];
            counter += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            void (^block)(void) = arr[i];
            block();
        }
    }
}
```

If run on the latest Xcode (4.6.3 (4H1503)) with the default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.2), the output for this will be

```
in this block, counter is 0
in this block, counter is 1
in this block, counter is 2
in this block, counter is 3
in this block, counter is 4
```

If these blocks were not copied to the heap, you would (probably--this is undefined behavior) see

```
in this block, counter is 4
in this block, counter is 4
in this block, counter is 4
in this block, counter is 4
in this block, counter is 4
```

because the pointers added to the array were all pointing to the stack-allocated (non-copied) block which--at the time that the blocks were executed--had captured a `counter` value of `4`.

In particular, this is the same behavior that you will get if you disable ARC.  Even if you call `retain` on the blocks before adding them to the array

```
[arr addObject:[block retain]];
```

you will still get the same ("broken") output, illustrating that **this is an ARC behavior, not a retain behavior in general**.

Note:

The two places where ARC's retain does not have the effect of Block_copy are

(1) retains done as part of initializing a `__strong` parameter variable

Immediately upon entering a function (or method), if an *object* is passed to that function (or method), that object will be retained (there is a strong reference to the object in the stack frame) and released when the function (or method) exits (the strong reference to the object is released).

This is just as true of blocks as it is true of any other object.  This phrase in the clang documentation means that even though the block is retained in this case, the block will not be copied by this retain.

(2) retains done as part of reading a `__weak` variable

Similarly, when a `__weak` variable is read into a `__strong` variable, a strong reference to the object is created, and the object is retained.

This is the case for blocks as well.  Blocks which are sent retain in this way (as a result of reading a `__weak` reference into a `__strong` reference), though, are not copied.

The cases where either of these two exceptions will cause you problems are rare.  In general, you don't need to worry about copying your blocks.

Comment: Unless I didn't get the documentation very well, your bold statement is generally wrong (as you yourself pointed out later in the answer). Retaining a block would do nothing. However you have a point: apparently there are cases when you would expect ARC to retain the block and instead a `Block_Copy` is performed. Bottom line, calling `retain` on a block which is still on the stack is still pointless. Good answer, though.

Comment: Quoting [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html): *Blocks “just work” when you pass blocks up the stack in ARC mode, such as in a return. You don’t have to call Block Copy any more. **You still need to use [^{} copy] when passing “down” the stack into arrayWithObjects: and other methods that do a retain.***

Comment: I have the impression that some of Apple's documentation may not be up to date with clang's.

Comment: In my particular test case I was creating a block literal, passing it as an argument to a function, and that function tried adding the argument to an NSArray. Definitely no automatic block_copy in that case. (XCode 4.6.3, runtime is iOS 5.0)

Comment: "In particular, when the block is added to a collection, it is copied!" Not necessarily. You yourself quoted the sentence that says "The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call."