# Objective C - Accessing typedef block pointer to add and remove from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsarray, typedef

I have a typedef

```
typedef void(^MyCompletionBlock)(NSDictionary *info);

- (void)populateWithCompletion:(MyCompletionBlock)completion
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array addObject:completion];
    [array removeObject:completion];
    NSAssert(array.count == 0, "Why");
}
```

The object is not removed from the array, the pointer to completion is something like

```
completion  MyCompletion    0x0000000102bcf30c
```

but when inspecting the contents of NSArray I see

```
[0] __NSMallocBlock__ * 0x105900610 0x0000000105900610
```

How do I get the underlying function pointer so that I can remove it from the array?  Also, why is the underlying function pointer added to the array instead of my typedef?

Comment: How did you call the `populateWithCompletion` method?

Comment: Related: [Why do NSBlocks have to be copied for storage in containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17385402/4244136)

Comment: What does `array[0]` return?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. Here is the complete code of my view controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self populateWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *info) {
        NSLog(@"%@", info);
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", @"got to here");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

typedef void(^MyCompletionBlock)(NSDictionary *info);

- (void)populateWithCompletion:(MyCompletionBlock)completion
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array addObject:completion];
    [array removeObject:completion];
    NSAssert(array.count == 0, @"Why");
}

@end
```

Launched the app. Console says "got to here".